# Javascript: why do functions treat array() and array[] differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parentheses, brackets

In class, teacher couldn't explain why tweets(i) failed and tweets[i] works:

```
  var tweets=["hi","who","when","where","bye"];
  alert("start");
  for (var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

    alert(tweets[i]);
  }
  alert("finish");
```

Comment: Because that is the convention as every programming language uses brackets to access an assay?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use tweets() because that means you are calling the tweets function, which doesn't exist. "tweets" is not a function it is an array.

Comment: Because tweets isn't a function, its an array and you access elements in an array using square brackets only.

Comment: Round brackets after an expression are always for function calls, and square brackets after an expression are always for property access. Array values are properties.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets are used for functions, so `array()` would be a function called `array`. Square brackets are used for arrays, so `array[]` would be an array. `array[0]` is the first entry in an array, `array(1)` would send `1` as an argument to a function called `array`.

And stop going to classes where the teacher can't explain something this simple. They clearly aren't a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason tweets(i) fails in this code snippet is because, when you say `tweets(i)`, javascript looks at it and says "oh, the code wants me to go find a function named tweets and execute it with a parameter named i."

When javascript sees `tweets[i]`, it says "oh, this isn't a function. The code wants me to find the number-i place in an array and give it back the value stored there.

In short, The reason `tweets(i)` doesn't work is because you're telling it to alert a function that you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

The `()` is a method invocation operator and the [x] is an member access operator. As array is not a function (e.g. `typeof array !== 'function'`), so you can only use member access operator on the array.

**Note:**

- I don't know the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) name of the above operators, will need expert explanation on them.
- A function is an object so you can use both operators on it

e.g.

```
var func = function() { return 'hello'; };

func.world = 'earth'
console.log(func());
console.log(func['world'])
console.log(func.world)
```